# Windows won't let me install Ubuntu Studio

Tags: software-installation

This is my first time getting Linux. I burned Linux to my disk. Every time i reset my computer it says "Windows could not install (or something like that). It says like something is missing. It worked when I installed it on  Virtual Box. But it won't let me install on my laptop. Please help.

Comment: What hardware and ubuntu version are you using? You probably need to follow [this guide](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/178596) to disable Secure Boot etc before you can install.

Comment: Are you trying to install with Wubi?  (Wubi doesn't work on the latest Windows)

Comment: I'm using Wubi. But it work on my Vitural Box. I was using Windows 10.

Comment: @IsaiahRodriguez Wubi does not work with Windows 10.  VirtualBox is not the same as Wubi.  Wubi installs inside of Windows.  VirtualBox is a 'file system' stored on Windows, but inside that 'file system' that is stored on 'virtual disks' is pure Linux, and is not the same as Wubi.

Comment: @ThomasW I mean that I was using Windows on Vitural Box. I was checking if it was my Laptop or my disk.

Comment: @Wilf I disabled Secure Boot I believe.. I'm using Ubuntu Studio 4.3 Trusty Tahr LTS

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of the partitions. If you have only made 1 partition then there is your issue. You need to make three free space partitions on what ever storage.

**The first partition is for Ubuntu and will be 50 Gigabytes (or more) in size.
The second partition is for your home partition and stores configuration files and your personal files such as music, pictures etc.
The third partition is for swap space and is used for intensive operations and suspending the computer.
When you have found the partition with free space, click on it and press the plus symbol (+) under the disk layout.**

This website is really helpful. If you have not seen already: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

On that website go the install ubuntu in the bottom middle of the page, and it will show a detailed explanation on installing ubuntu.

If there are any issues please reply or comment.

Comment: There is one big problem... My Window expired. I can't really do anything on my laptop. I have a other computer that I can use. But I want to install Linux on my laptop.

Comment: And I actually fully restated my laptop. So I have a lot of space now.

Comment: Are you able to use ubuntu via the live disk?

Comment: It keeps getting a error saying something like "Windows could not something something. There might be something missing" or something like that

Comment: So you can't even enter the ubuntu environment, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Is there anyway were I can show you what I'm seeing? And sorry if I have bad Grammer.

Comment: Just while I attempt in solving this problem. Can I ask where did you download the ISO file from? Because it seems that if it says something is missing: 1. The application you used to create a live CD may not have been correct. Furthermore, try installing the live cd (iso) on a usb instead of a CD and boot of that.

Comment: Take a photo on your phone.

Comment: I downloaded it from here https://ubuntustudio.org/download/

Comment: How do I send pictures. Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: I think post in your description or add an answer box.

Comment: It won't let me. Is there any other way? Give me your email. And see if that would work.